# CKEditor - Copy and paste link ie 11

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor

I have a problem with the CKEditor and IE 11.In the CKEditor i write a link and i define a style without an underline. But when i paste it in IE 11, the link is underline and in the source code, the link is updated with underline balise.

I made some research but i don't know if it's a bug of CKEditor or a missing line in the configuration file.

Thanks,

Edit : 
Sorry if my english is not perfect...

My CKEditor is integrated in the Java Liferay Portal. The version of CkEditor is 4.0.3
In some forms of the portal, the CKEditor is integrate. When i use it in the classic Editing version of the CKEditor i insert a link with the link button. Then i copy and paste it (ctrl+c - ctrl+v) and the second link i have is underline.
I try with good browser like Firefox or chrome and it works, the style of the link is not updated.

Here the configuration of my CKEditor :

```
var config = ckEditor.config;

config.autoParagraph = false;

config.autoSaveTimeout = 3000;

config.bodyClass = 'html-editor <%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(colorSchemeCssClass) %> <%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(cssClasses) %>';

config.closeNoticeTimeout = 8000;

config.contentsCss = ['<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(cssPath) %>/aui.css', '<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(cssPath) %>/main.css'];

config.startupOutlineBlocks = true;
```

```
config.contentsLangDirection = '<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(contentsLanguageDir) %>';

config.contentsLanguage = '<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(contentsLanguageId.replace("iw_", "he_")) %>';

config.entities = false;

config.extraPlugins = 'a11yhelpbtn,media,scayt,wsc';

config.allowedContent = true;

<c:if test="<%= inlineEdit %>">
    config.extraPlugins += ',ajaxsave,restore';
</c:if>

config.height = 265;

config.language = '<%= HtmlUtil.escapeJS(languageId.replace("iw_", "he_")) %>';

config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;

config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = true;

config.resize_enabled = <%= resizable %>;

<c:if test="<%= resizable %>">
    config.resize_dir = 'vertical';
</c:if>

config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'liferayStyles';

config.title = false;

config.toolbar_coeContributor = [
    ['Styles'],
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'SpecialChar'],
    ['Undo', 'Redo','RemoveFormat'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent'],
    ['Maximize']
];

config.toolbar_editInPlace = [
    ['Styles'],
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'SpecialChar'],
    ['Undo', 'Redo'],
    ['SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    <c:if test="<%= showSource %>">
    ['Source'],
    </c:if>
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent'], ['RemoveFormat'],['Maximize'],
    ['A11YBtn']
];

config.toolbar_email = [
    [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    '/',
    ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],

    <c:if test="<%= showSource %>">
    ['Source'],
    </c:if>
    ['Link', 'Unlink'],
    ['Image'],['Maximize'],
    ['A11YBtn']
];



config.toolbar_liferay = [
    ['Styles', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],      
    <c:if test="<%= inlineEdit %>">
        ['AjaxSave', '-', 'Restore'],
    </c:if>
    ['Subscript', 'Superscript'],
    '/',
    ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ['Find', 'Replace', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','HorizontalRule','Blockquote','CreateDiv','IconsCoe'],
    '/',

    <c:if test="<%= !inlineEdit && showSource %>">
        ['Source'],     
    </c:if>
    ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor','LinkCoE','IconsCoe','FlagsCoe'],
    ['Image', 'Flash', <c:if test="<%= XugglerUtil.isEnabled() %>">'Audio', 'Video',</c:if> 'Videoloader', 'Table', '-', 'SpecialChar'],
    ['ShowBlocks'],['Maximize'],
    ['A11YBtn']
];

config.toolbar_liferayArticle = [
    ['Styles', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],      
    <c:if test="<%= inlineEdit %>">
        ['AjaxSave', '-', 'Restore'],
    </c:if>
    ['Subscript', 'Superscript'],
    ['Maximize'],
    '/',
    ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ['Find', 'Replace', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','HorizontalRule','CreateDiv'],
    '/',

    <c:if test="<%= !inlineEdit && showSource %>">
    ['Source'],
    </c:if>
    ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor','LinkCoE','IconsCoe','FlagsCoe'],
    ['Image', 'Flash', <c:if test="<%= XugglerUtil.isEnabled() %>">'Audio', 'Video',</c:if> 'Videoloader', 'Table', '-', 'SpecialChar'],
    ['ShowBlocks'],['Maximize'],
    ['A11YBtn']
];

config.toolbar_phone = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ['Image', 'Link', 'Unlink'],['Maximize']
];

config.toolbar_simple = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ['Image', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Table'],['Maximize']
];

config.extraPlugins = 'link_coe,videoloader,icons_coe';

config.toolbar_tablet = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ['Image', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['Styles', 'FontSize'],['Maximize']
];

CKEDITOR.on(
    'dialogDefinition',
    function(event) {
        var dialogDefinition = event.data.definition;

        var onShow = dialogDefinition.onShow;

        dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
            if (typeof onShow === 'function') {
                onShow.apply(this, arguments);
            }

            if (window.top != window.self) {
                var editorElement = this.getParentEditor().container;

                var documentPosition = editorElement.getDocumentPosition();

                var dialogSize = this.getSize();

                var x = documentPosition.x + ((editorElement.getSize('width', true) - dialogSize.width) / 2);
                var y = documentPosition.y + ((editorElement.getSize('height', true) - dialogSize.height) / 2);

                this.move(x, y, false);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Please update your post with more details. How and where do you define the style for a link? Does it work in other browsers other than IE11? What is your CKEditor version and its configuration? How do you initialize CKEditor on your page, is it classic editor or inline editor?

Comment: This is a really old CKEditor version integrated with another product. Try reaching out to the Liferay community (tag the question appropriately here on StackOverflow, too). If you have issues with styling differing in your editors, check the stylesheets that are loaded for these editors - they probably differ.

Comment: If someone want to know, it's a Liferay issue ! I open a ticket on Liferay support and theywill deliver a patch as soon as possible !

Comment: @Amar any update for this?